# How can i set the variable to a replica of the list and not a reference in python classes?

Tags: python-3.x, class, variables

I am trying to make my first Nural Network, and I am trying to make a variable containing the old value of a variable, but when I change the original the copy also changes. I think it is because it may be a reference and not a separate list an I wonder how I can make it separate. Thanks

```
import random

class NN:
    def __init__(self, inputs=2, outputs=1, c=0.0001):
        self.weights = []
        self.change = c
        for i in range(inputs):
            self.weights.append([])
            for j in range(outputs):
                self.weights[i].append(random.uniform(-1, 1))

    def train(self):

        oldWeights = self.weights  #this is the copy

        for i in range(len(self.weights)):
            for j in range(len(self.weights[i])):
                self.weights[i][j] += random.uniform(-1, 1) * self.change #Here is the changestrong text
                if (self.weights[i][j]) < -1: self.weights[i][j] = -1
                elif self.weights[i][j] > 1: self.weights[i][j] = 1

Test_NN = NN()
Test_NN.train()
```